# Complicated responsive table with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I am trying to get with following data with table.. on mobile view it is not working perfectly: I am trying to achieve to achieve it through bootstrap.
It includes colspan and rowspan too.

HTML as follow:

```
<div id="no-more-tables">
<table border="1" id="pricing" width="100%" class="table col-sm-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" scope="col" style="background-color:#CD3E27; color:#FFFFFF;">Baner Packages - Per Month</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The Mesh Premium</td>
    <td>The Mesh Eco</td>
    <td>The Mesh Ladies<br></td>
    <td>The Mesh Impact</td>
    <td>The Mesh Moonlighters</td>
    <td>The Mesh 9-9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&#8377; 7,500/-</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&#8377; 6,000/-</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&#8377; 5,500/-</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&#8377; 5,500/-</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&#8377; 3,500/-</td>
    <td>&#8377; 500/- Non-AC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&#8377; 750/- AC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Includes 24*7 AC</td>
    <td>Non-AC</td>
    <td>Non-AC</td>
    <td>Non-AC</td>
    <td>Non-AC</td>
    <td>One Day Pass</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
```

CSS as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        #no-more-tables table,
        #no-more-tables thead,
        #no-more-tables tbody,
        #no-more-tables th,
        #no-more-tables td,
        #no-more-tables tr {
        display: block;
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        #no-more-tables thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
        }

        #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        #no-more-tables td {
        /* Behave like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:left;
        }

        #no-more-tables td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
        }

        /*
        Label the data
        */
        #no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
        }
```

JS fiddle link as above: https://jsfiddle.net/anujoshi10/n0gL4y1g/
                         http://jsfiddle.net/anujoshi10/5t2syp13/

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: just use `col-xs` for mobile device

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap Responsive Table i use this Trick: Work Perfect for me.

Visit Link and try to follow Examples  http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

Hope This Helps!
Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. But in my table there is a rowspan and colspan too. So I am not able to do responsive solution for the same.